# Estrutura correta para trabalhar com java (JSP)

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Estou começando a desenvolver com java (Jsp).
E gostaria de saber a estrutura correta de se trabalhar (apenas com java "puro").

Seria essa:

model (Classes com get e set)
   dao   (classes que estende a classe de conexão) (para cada classe do pacote model eu tenho uma DAO que acessa o banco)

preciso ter outro pacote para ter as regras de negócios? ou devo implementar no model?

Comment: Olá @Teuassuri, tudo bem? É um pouco difícil responder uma pergunta tão ampla de arquitetura pois existe mais de "uma maneira correta" de desenhar as camadas de um aplicativo em java, tudo depende do seu projeto. De um lado temos o Martin Fowler falando dos perigos de modelos anêmicos, do outro, anos e anos de cultura "procedural" e design de camadas de serviços (seja em projetos com EJB, seja em projetos Spring, etc). Não sei se isso ajuda, mas o que posso dizer é, procure se informar sobre domínio ricos e camadas de negócios, use o que for melhor para o seu projeto (que pode ser os dois ;).

Comment: Outro comentário relevante... Se você for trabalhar com java web "puro" (seja lá o que isso for), não se esqueça dos `Servlets`. Eles possuem um papel importante: interagir com o modelo e/ou camada de negócios, controlar navegação, etc, de maneira que os *jsps* possam se limitar à camada de *view*. Evite *scriptlets* e coisas do gênero; deixe a sua camada de *view* limpa; os *servlets* "frontais" devem se encarregar disso tudo e fazer *forward* para os *jsps*, os últimos devem ser "burros" (apenas exibir resultados).

Answer (score 1):

Já que você perguntou de padrões...

O mais comum é o padrão MVC(Model-View-Controller):

- Model: Classe onde está a lógica de negócio e lógica do programa. EX.: EJBs, Beans, DAOs.
- Controller: Classe que pega requisições feitas pela View e passa as mesmas para o Model.
- View: Classe que mostra os dados para o cliente. EX.: páginas JSP ou JSF

Sobre o "java puro", só use-o nas classes e servlets, NUNCA faça isso em páginas JSP. Ao invés disso, procure uma alternativa, como o [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/).

Aconselho a você dar uma olhada em alguns tutoriais na internet, sobre MVC no geral. Para aprender mais sobre o padrão, usei [este tutorial de MVC no PHP](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceito-de-mvc-e-sua-funcionalidade-usando-o-php/22324), [a página da wikipédia em inglês sobre MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) e [o tutorial do TheJavaGeek para MVC no Java](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/).

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Eu indicaria que você começasse pelo básico, pegasse exemplos simples de padrões MVC(Model-View-Controller) para dar início aos seus estudos de arquitetura e java web.

Aqui, abaixo, vão alguns links interessantes sobre java web, utilizandos arquiteturas MVC bem básicas.

Apostila Java web da Caelum, que cobre desde o básico do java web, até a utilização de frameworks mais complexos como o Spring MVC, além de apresentar padrões de projetos essenciais, como o DAO Pattern(Padrão de acesso a dados):
https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/

Tutorial simples em inglês bem rápido:
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/